# Insert different rows between Table A and Table B into Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two exactly identical tables. Table A has e.g. 100 rows, Table B has 60 rows. Now I want to insert the "missing" rows from Table A into Table B. 
To find the different rows I would use:

```
select * from tableA where language = 4
union
select * from tableB where language = 4
```

How do I use this code correctly with the "Insert into" statement?
My idea:

```
Insert into tableB
(Select * from tableA where language = 4
union
select * from tableB where language = 4)
```

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried EXCEPT?

Comment: Do you have any identity of both table ?

Answer (score 2):

UNION may be an option but it would cause duplications. I would prefer MINUS operation.

```
insert into tableB (
select * from tableA where language=4
MINUS
select * from tableB where language=4)
```

Comment: UNION eliminates duplicate yes. But with union code, you are going to select all 100 rows, which are in A and B. And you are going to insert them in B again. That will cause the duplication. Not the UNION operator.

We need the rows which are IN A and NOT IN B. Solution for this would be a MINUS operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into tableB
(Select * from tableA where language = 4
EXCEPT
select * from tableB where language = 4)
```

Perhaps `EXCEPT ALL` should be used, treats duplicates differently.

Answer (score 0):

**Outer Join**

```
INSERT INTO TableB (Column1,Column2) 
  SELECT DISTINCT
    a.Column1 ,
    a.Column2 ... more column
  FROM    TableA AS a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS b ON b.Column1 = a.Column1 
                                          AND b.Column2 = a.Column2 
    WHERE b.Colum2 IS NULL AND b.Colum1 IS NULL ;
```

**Not Exists**

```
INSERT INTO TableB (Column1,Column2) 
SELECT  a.Column1 ,
    a.Column2...
FROM    Table1 AS a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM   Table2 AS b
                 WHERE  b.Column1 = a.Column1 
                        AND b.Column2= a.Column2);
```

**Except**

```
INSERT INTO TableB (Column1,Column2) 
SELECT  Column1,
    Column2
FROM    TaBLE1
EXCEPT
SELECT  Column1,
    Column2
FROM    #TaBLE2;
```